# JQuery - prevent triggering multiple events

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using events in JQuery to communicate between different JavaScript modules. So in one of the modules I have something like this:

```
$(window).on('updateStatusRequest', function(ev) {
    // Send updateStatus event after fetching data
    data = fetchData();
    $(window).trigger('updateStatus', data);
});
```

And this data fetch can potentially last long (it sends HTTP request outside) before finishing. Here's a problem I'm thinking about now - what if there are a lot of 'updateStatusRequest' triggered and the function didn't fetch data yet? I want to prevent multiple data fetches in that case so I'm thinking of something like this:

```
$(window).on('updateStatusRequest', function(ev) {
    $(window).off('updateStatusRequest', this);
    // Send updateStatus event after fetching data
    data = fetchData();
    $(window).trigger('updateStatus', data);
    $(window).on('updateStatusRequest', this);
});
```

So I want to turn callback off during its execution. Unfortunately the approach above don't work. What is the proper way to do that?

Comment: Hm..."`fetchData` is taking a long time"...before we continue on this, can you please assure me that you are NOT using synchronous requests?

Comment: I'm using JQuery's `getJSON()` to fetch data, I haven't found in its documentation whether is asynchronous or not but I'm assuming it is as it makes contact with the outside.

Comment: Alternatively to Howard's answer you can just wrap the content of your function in an if statement, that checks for a global variable, if (!fetching){fetching = true;...} and set fetching to false again on fetchData completion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a callback when you add the event handler back in.  Something like this should work:

```
$(window).on('updateStatusRequest', function(ev) {
    newFunction();
});

var newFunction = function (){
    $(window).off('updateStatusRequest');
    data = fetchData();
    $(window).trigger('updateStatus', data);
    $(window).on('updateStatusRequest', function (){
        newFunction();
    });
}
```

Although, I would probably use a promise instead of adding/removing the event handlers...

Comment: Thanks for that promise reference, will probably use that as it is more clear

Comment: no problem - promises are great, I use them all the time.

Answer (score 0):

Use [JQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) and turn async off